# Use content of cell as text for label in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A        
1    Time
2
3
```

I would like use the word written in `Cell A1` as the text for a label on the `UserForm`. Therefore, I tried to go with this VBA:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

However, this code does not use the content from `Cell A1` as text for the label. 
 What do I have to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Do you want to use `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` event instead of `Label1_Click` ? It will update the caption as soon as form is activated. If no, then add `DoEvents` function above end sub and give a try.

Comment: It will work if you click on the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is changing `Private Sub Label1_Click` to `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```